# Почему не грузится фрэйм?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <title></title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style_ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" /><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<frameset rows="44,*" cols="*">
    <frame src="http://meethemes.com" scrolling="no" noresize>
    <frame src="http://meethemes.com" scrolling="auto" noresize>
</frameset>

</body>
</html>
```

Не понимаю, почему ничего не загружается. Первый раз тег использую. Может что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Body оставь , frameset перед /head нужно ставить) и все работает как надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, ребятки.. Надо было просто удалить к чертям '<body>'

Comment: @inferus-w , обращайся!